# Vuex getters with params

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am wondering why can't I use vuex getter with property with default value like this:

```
getters: {
  getTest: (state, property = 'current') => {
     return state.test[property]
  }
}
```

and when I use it like this `getTest.includes('something')` it doesn't work but if I use it like this `getTest().includes('something')` it works?

Since when there are no params used it works without `()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access

```js
getters: {
  getTest: (state) => (property = 'current') => {
    return state.test[property]
  }
}

// example usage
this.getTest().includes('something')
```

Comment: Then you must have called it wrong! Show how you call it.

Comment: `getTest.includes('something')` and `getTest().includes('something')`, from `...mapGetters(['getTest'])`

Comment: `getTest().includes('something')` will 100% work, based on the docs and my personal experience. Let me edit my answer

Comment: Yeah I am asking why do I need to add `()` if I am not passing anything and there is the default value when I am not passing anything? Like when there are no params in getter. It is not a big deal I can use () but I need to look through 10000 lines to find every getter call that is not having () at the end

Comment: Because the getter returns a function. and you need to call the function.

Comment: It only "works without params" b/c you coded it wrong, originally. If you try to use the getter in my answer without params, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of the getters is the other getters :

> Getters will also receive other getters as the 2nd argument

(https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#property-style-access)

So your `property` parameter will be an array, thus `state.test[property]` always returns `undefined`

To use a getter as a function with parameters, you need to make your getter return a function, as shown here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access

Answer (score 0):

```
getters: {
    getCarteiraPeloId: (state) => (id) => {
        return state.carteiras.find(thing => thing.id === id) || { nome: 'Não Encontrado' }
    }
```

That is it.